# Regular expression in Javascript: table of positions instead of table of occurrences

Tags: javascript, regex

Regular expressions are most powerful. However, the result they return is sometimes useless:

For example:

I want to manage a CSV string using semicolons.
I define a string like:

```
var data = "John;Paul;Pete;Stuart;George";
```

If I use the instruction:

```
var tab = data.match(/;/g)
```

after what, "tab" contains an array of 4 ";" :

```
tab[0]=";", tab[1]=";", tab[2]=";", tab[3]=";"
```

This array is not useful in the present case, because I knew it even before using the regular expression.

Indeed, what I want to do is 2 things:

- 1stly: Suppress the 4th element (not "Stuart" as "Stuart", but "Stuart" as 4th element)
- 2ndly: Replace the 3rd element by "Ringo" so as to get back (to where you once belonged!) the following result:

  `data == "John;Paul;Ringo;George";`

In this case, I would greatly prefer to obtain an array giving the positions of semicolons:

```
tab[0]=4, tab[1]=9, tab[2]=14 tab[3]=21
```

instead of the useless (in this specific case)

```
tab[0]=";", tab[1]=";", tab[2]=";", tab[3]=";"
```

So, here's my question: Is there a way to obtain this numeric array using regular expressions?

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, but I guess you're looking for `split`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: What about the list of strings _between_ the semicolons? These are easy to obtain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get `tab[0]=4, tab[1]=9, tab[2]=14 tab[3]=21`, you can do

```
var tab = [];
var startPos = 0;
var data = "John;Paul;Pete;Stuart;George";

while (true) {

    var currentIndex = data.indexOf(";", startPos);

    if (currentIndex == -1) {
        break;
    }

    tab.push(currentIndex);
    startPos = currentIndex;

}
```

But if the result wanted is `"John;Paul;Ringo;George"`, you can do

```
var tab = data.split(';'); // Split the string into an array of strings

tab.splice(3, 1); // Suppress the 4th element
tab[2] = "Ringo"; // Replace the 3rd element by "Ringo"

var str = tab.join(';');   // Join the elements of the array into a string
```

The second approach is maybe better in your case.

- [String.split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)
- [Array.splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)
- [Array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Answer (score 1):

You should try a different approach, using `split`.
`tab = data.split(';')` will return an array of the form

```
tab[0]="John", tab[1]="Paul", tab[2]="Pete", tab[3]="Stuart", tab[4]="George"
```

You should be able to achieve your goal with this array.

Comment: Additionally there is the `join` method of String, which would allow him to use `var tab = data.split(';'); tab[3] = 'Ringo'; tab = tab.join(';');`. You might want to add that. ;)

Comment: @Derija93 that's a method of Array, not String

Comment: Thank you for your help, but in fact, I already knew the powerful pair split/join, that I often use. But, you know, my problem here is to find the quickest way of re-building my global CSV while suppressing an internal element (the 4th out of 5 in my example above), and I was wondering if regular expressions might help to make it easier? Thanks anyway to try and help me.

Comment: For deleting every 4th element in a csv, you can use `/^(([^;]+){3}));[^;]+;(([^;]+)+)/$1$3/g`.

Comment: Sorry, Vince, I don't understand your regex. Firstly, I don't catch the use of "([^]+){3}", that seems to mean "3 non-';' characters" and not "3 strings separated by ';'". Moreover, an internal string may be empty, like in "paul;;;ringo" (2 poor dead men out of 4!), so shouldn't it be "([^;]*;){3}" instead? 
 Finally, could you explain the final syntax, that I don't know: "/$1$3/g" ?
 Thanks for helping.

Comment: You misread my regex ;-) Actually it's `([^;]+){3})`, not `([^]+){3}`. That's `one or more non-;-characters, exactly 3 times`. Since regexes are greedy, this should capture every char between two `;` until it found 3 of them. It would also work, if you'd use `*` instead of `+`, I didn't consider empty fields. Finally `/$1$3/g` means, it substitutes the match with the contents of the first and third `()` (they are counted by the position of the opening `(`). I hope, I could clear things up a bit. And last but not least, use ` instead of " for code snippets ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why use a `regex` to perform this operation? You have a built-in function split, which can split your string based on the delimiter you pass.

```
var data = "John;Paul;Pete;Stuart;George";
var temp=data.split(';');
temp[0],temp[1]...
```